# how to enable scroll inside the drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a selection drop down in my popup.when we add more list of items it goes out side the popup while showing list of items
here is the code i have used

```
<span class="style2 title span2">Subject</span>

<select id="ddSubject" style="width: 220px; overflow: auto;">
    <option value="-1">Select Subject</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: do not use overflow auto, set its height and set overflow: scroll

Comment: Have you tried to use some plugin? Like `select2` or `chosen`?

Comment: i set the height and overflow scroll its showing the same result..

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Scrollheight in your CSS. Something like this.

```
.scrollheight{
   max-height: 600px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

After that use it in your html.

```
 <div class="panel-body scrollheight">
    .......
```

Comment: scroll is showing outside the drop down field not inside the dropdown

Comment: You must call that class inside your dropdown list class not in the dropdown class. I'm supposing that you have somekind of class like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.select{
        height:100px;
        overflow:scroll;
    }
```